# How to use Zend GData in a Symfony2 project

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, symfony

I'm working on a project based on Symfony2 framework, and I would like to be able to search for Youtube videos and display them. For that, I've been trying to figure out a way to load Zend GData classes into my Symfony2 controller, but there's very little or no documentation about this topic. So I would like to know if there's a way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At which step are you? 1. Pull the Zend library into your library folder, 2. Setup the autoloader to handle it, 3. Instantiate objects, 4. Use the objects according to it's documentation

Comment: I have the Zend Library into my library folder, but I don't know how to setup the autoloader to handle it in order to be able to Instantiate the objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. add this line to the namespaces array of your autoload.php file:

   'Zend'             => **DIR**.'/../vendor/Zend/library',
2. use the classes just as you would do in a zend app:

   $gdata = new \Zend\GData\GData();

It might be useful to register and use some classes as services, but that's another topic...

Answer (score 5):

1. Create the following directory structure in your vendor/ dir:

   - vendor/
   - -> zend/
   - --> lib/
   - ---> Zend/
   - ----> [Zend directory from Zend GData package]
   - --> README
   - --> LICENSE
2. Register 'Zend_' prefix in your app/autoload.php:

   $loader->registerPrefixes(array(
   // ... Some previous prefixes like Twig and Twig_Extensions
   'Zend_'            => **DIR**.'/../vendor/zend/lib',
   ));
3. According to [Fabien's presentation](http://fabien.potencier.org/media/talk/2009/symfony-and-zend-framework-together-2009.pdf) about symfony 1.4 and ZF integration you also need to dynamically change your include_path. Add the following code at the bottom of your app/autoload.php:

   // Zend Framework GData needs a special autoload fix too
   set_include_path(**DIR**.'/../vendor/zend/lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());